# How to check all multiple tables are updated?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

While writing stored procedure, i have remove set no count on and check whether multiple rows are affected to check whether the table values are affected or not.

Then I have realized it will give bad performance.

Then I have implemented like @@rowcount.

But for checking one table this  will be the good idea.

In stored procedure, I will update more than one table and delete more than one table.

**How to return whether the values are updated/deleted in efficient way to the server side (where i will use .ExecuteScalar)?**

Comment: Please add some code displaying your issue as well explaining what you have done and tried.

Comment: Just a workaround. Assign the @@rowcount into a variable. After each statement is executed, then multiple the @@rowcount with the value present in the variable. If all tables are affected, then you will get a NON-ZERO value as result or it will be ZERO.

Comment: @GopakumarN.Kurup Thank you. I think we are sailing on the same boat :-p.. I have tried this. Is there any alternate? Is this ok to continue with..

Comment: @JeevaJsb :) Add an output variable with the above value. I assume this is the best way to attain this.

Answer (score 0):

**Variant 1:** Create `trigger` to log changes into table and after then get information from this table.

**Variant 2:** Use system variables `@@rowcount` to get information about rows effected.

**Variant 3:** Get information about rows effected and use your `variable` or output `select` or `output statement` which can store number of changed rows

**Variant 4:** Rewrite your code to pattern: `int numberOfRecords = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();`